# Flink 1.17 Upgrade Resulting in Ever Increasing Checkpoint Size

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

[Flink checkpoint sizes across 90 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyyl2.png)

We have a few Flink services which we recently upgraded from 1.13 to 1.17. No other significant code changes have been made. Our apps checkpoint at a 2 minute interval. Post upgrade, we noticed that the checkpoint size kept increasing. It was only reset when we redeployed the application without using the recent checkpoint. As you see in the image, the orange-ish brown line was checkpoint size during the Flink 1.13. Since then it has been Flink 1.17, and the drops indicate points of redeployment and starting fresh.

What are the possible reasons for this behaviour?

All our states have a TTL. All our Windows have their respective aggregate functions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried to compare the default flink configurations between 1.13 and 1.17 to see if there is a difference in how state/memory is managed?

Can you downgrade to 1.13 to see if you can go back to your initial checkpoint size.   This might be code/state related and not the version, but cant be 100% sure until you downgrade to 1.13 with your latest code and verify that the checkpoint size does go down or not.

Comment: Did you make _any_ configuration changes? Which state backend is this (is your state in RocksDB, or on the heap)?

Comment: Have you used any of the claim modes that were introduced with Flink 1.15? https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/release-notes/flink-1.15/#checkpoints